# git-ftp: Is not a git command

Tags: git

I am trying to install [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/INSTALL.md#windows) under my windows 8.1 install in my `git version 2.17.0.windows.1`

I did the following:

```
cd /c/"Program Files"/Git
git clone https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp git-ftp.git
cd git-ftp.git && chmod +x git-ftp
cp /c/"Program Files"/Git/git-ftp.git/git-ftp /c/"Program Files"/Git/bin/git-ftp
```

However, when restarting on a fresh git console as admin, I get the following:

```
$ git ftp
git: 'ftp' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        fetch
```

The [official installation instructions](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) also `cp` the `git-ftp` file to the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

*UPDATE*
After executing I found my execution path:

```
$ git --exec-path
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core
```

I copied the file:

```
cp /c/"Program Files"/Git/git-ftp.git/git-ftp /c/"Program Files"/Git/bin/git-ftp
```

The file is now located:

[image]

However, I still get the above error that `git: 'ftp' is not a git command.`.

Comment: The correct directory is whatever `git --exec-path` outputs.

Comment: At first glance, you copied it to `c:\Program Files` not `C:\Program Files (x86)`. It should go where `Git/bin` is.

Comment: @o11c The output I from `$ git --exec-path` is `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core`

Comment: @Schwern Please have a look at my update.

Comment: @Anna.Klee I'm not 100% sure about Git on Windows, but normally Git command programs like `git-ftp` have to 1) be in your PATH and 2) executable. Can you execute `git-ftp`?

Comment: @Schwern Git/bin is not on PATH, which is generally uselessly-empty on windows. `git --exec-path` is searched regardless of path, though.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same problem after these install instructions.

Solution: I've copied file `git-ftp` from `c:\Program Files\Git\bin\` to the folder `c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\` and command `gif ftp push -s` was finally successful.

Thank you all for you hints above! Mike

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to copy it since it will possibly make it incompatible when you update it to a newer version. And it's unnecessary to have it twice on the disk. Rather create a symbolic link.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy - Good point! I tried to create symboli link ( Win10) in command line as administrator with the syntax: mklink "c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-ftp" "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git-ftp". > Symbolic mlink was created, but Git Bash gave me answer: $ git ftp
env: ‘C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\\git-ftp’: No such file or directory :(

Comment: Your symbolic link is missing the `exe` extension. I would start with that.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Original **git-ftp** file downloaded to c:\Program Files\Git\bin\ is also missing **exe** extension. I've copied file as is.